# How can I generate a time domain square pulse that relies on frequency and not zero centered at MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fft, pulse, square

I want to create a square pulse, then use FFT on it. However, this code does not relies on central frequency to generate a pulse, and it is centered at 0 in time and frequency.

```
fs=500; %sampling frequency
T=0.2; %width of the rectangle pulse in seconds
t=-0.5:1/fs:0.5; %time base
x=rectpuls(t,T); %generating the square wave
plot(t,x,'k');
title(&#91;'Rectangular Pulse width=', num2str(T),'s']);
xlabel('Time(s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
L=length(x);
NFFT = 1024;
X = fftshift(fft(x,NFFT)); %FFT with FFTshift for both negative &amp; positive frequencies
f = fs*(-NFFT/2:NFFT/2-1)/NFFT; %Frequency Vector
figure;
plot(f,abs(X)/(L),'r');
title('Magnitude of FFT');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Magnitude |X(f)|');
```

this will give the following plot:

[image: Square pulse FFT]

I tried mixing this code( Gaussian pulse) with the square pulse, but it didn't work.

```
lambda= 800e-9;%Wavelength
c=3*10.^8;%lLight speed
fc = c/lambda; % Actual Frequency of light [THz]
fsamp=fc*10; %sampling frequency
fs=1/fsamp; %Unit Time in [fs]
Ls=1000; %Length of signal
sigma=lambda/1e+8;% Pulse duration
ts=(0:Ls-1)*fs; %time base
t0 = max(ts)/2; % Used to centering the pulse
gauss = (exp(-2*log(2)*(ts-t0).^2/(sigma)^2)).*cos(-2*pi*fc*(ts-t0));
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(ts,real(gauss),'b');
title('Gaussian Pulse in Time Domain');
xlabel('Time(s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
grid on;
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(Ls);
X = fft(gauss,NFFT)/Ls;
freq = 0.5*fsamp*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1); % (full range) Frequency Vector
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(freq,abs(X(1:NFFT/2+1))) 
title('FFT of the Gaussian Pulse');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Magnitude |X(f)|');
grid on;
```

Which will give:

[image: Gaussian pulse FFT]

As can be seen in this code, the unit time relies on the central frequency and it's not centered at zero. I think its because of fs, T, and t. How can I make it change time whenever I change frequency, while not centered at time and frequency equal 0?

Comment: Remove the fftshift if you dont want it centered at zero

Comment: I tried it, and it gave me two opposite signal at the edge of the plot (at -250 and 250). I want to keep its shape while not zero centered.

Comment: Multiplying with linear phase term in time domain leads to shifting in frequency domain. Search for frequency shifting property of fft